# Updated instructions for setting up TileCache on IIS 7.5?

Tags: tilecache

This article seems great...but it is hard [for me] to follow when setting up for IIS 7.5:

http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2008/02/03/setting-up-tilecache-on-iis/

Any updated instructions available with latest versions of TileCache and IIS?

Comment: I've posted similar instructions at http://coreyalix.pbworks.com/w/page/55735758/TileCache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing a google search and then limiting results to the past year I was able to find [these instructions for IIS 7](http://www.esdmdata.co.uk/tilecache-on-iis7-how-to).